# std::sort doesn't recognise iterator category

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, iterator

My implementation of some vector iterator:

```
class iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, int> {
    Vector<T> *vector;
    size_t position;

public:
    iterator(Vector<T> *vector_, size_t idx) {...};
    iterator(const iterator &it) {...};
    friend bool operator == (const iterator &a, const iterator &b) {...};
    friend bool operator > (const iterator &a, const iterator &b) {...};
    friend bool operator < (const iterator &a, const iterator &b) {...};
    friend bool operator >= (const iterator &a, const iterator &b) {...};
    friend bool operator <= (const iterator &a, const iterator &b) {...};
    friend bool operator != (const iterator &a, const iterator &b) {...};
    iterator &operator = (const iterator &b) {...};
    T operator * () {...};
    iterator &operator ++ () {...}
    iterator &operator -- () {...}

    std::ptrdiff_t operator - (const iterator &b) const {...}
};
```

But for come reasons calling `std::sort(vector.begin(), vector.end())` outputs errors like `no operator +=`, which point to the fact `std::sort` treats my iterators like random access. Why?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, `input_iterator_tag` is not the right tag for this iterator, and `int` is not the right `value_type`.

Comment: Apparently you haven't read the documentation for `std::sort`, but are programming by guessing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) requires `RandomAccessIterator`s. While it may recognize you gave it incompatible iterators it still doesn't work.

Comment: I would add that `std::sort` requires a **mutable** `RandomAccessIterator`. You should provide `operator*()` that returns an l-value reference. For example, Libstdc++-v3 requires this (within insertion sort, which is invoked from `sort`).